# Doppio: how does multi-threading work and are there any limitations?

Tags: javascript, java, multithreading, web-worker, doppio

I'm investigating using [DoppioJVM](https://github.com/plasma-umass/doppio) for porting a (graphical) Java app to Javascript. For this it would be good to know how it handles Java threads in the Javascript environment. Specifically:

- Can the threads share memory?
- Can the threads run on different CPU cores?
- Any other limitations/issues threads might have in Doppio compared to a usual JVM

Comment: You can find answers to all of these questions [in their paper.](https://plasma-umass.github.io/doppio-demo/paper.pdf) They use Web Workers to simulate threads and Web Workers [do make use of different cores](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers).

Comment: Re, "Can the threads share memory?" If they can't do that, then they're not threads.  Threads, by definition, are different executions of the same code, in the same virtual address space.

Comment: Re, "Can the threads run on different CPU cores?" According to the web site that you linked to, no:  It says, "[We currently have a basic thread implementation in Doppio that should be mostly spec-conformant. Since JavaScript is essentially single threaded, only one thread runs at a time.](http://plasma-umass.github.io/doppio/about.html)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking through [their paper on Doppio](https://github.com/plasma-umass/doppio/issues/127), it seems like it the JVM runs in the main Javascript thread. Or, according to this [github issue on running Doppio in a worker](https://github.com/plasma-umass/doppio/issues/127), it runs fine in a web worker. However, it seems like the Doppio thread pool is a pool of simulated threads all in the same "real" thread, and so these don't map to web workers. This seems to be confirmed by [the about page on Doppio](http://plasma-umass.github.io/doppio/about.html) that states

> Since JavaScript is essentially single threaded, only one thread runs at a time

So to answer my own questions...

> Can the threads share memory?

Yes, since they're all in the main Javascript thread / a single worker

> Can the threads run on different CPU cores?

No, for the same reason as above

> Any other limitations/issues threads might have in Doppio compared to a usual JVM

A major one from their paper, which admittedly isn't multi-threading specific, is that there is a 24x to 42x slowdown

---

Thanks to comments + links posted in comments by Mike C and James Large.